# Бинарная сериализация. Запись в файл

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. Проблема в том что я не могу присвоить и сохранить новое значение.
На каждом уровне карты есть своя начальная история, которая появляется при первом вхождении игрока на карту. Соответственно я хочу сохранить весь текст в файл что бы потом его вытягивать. Для этого я придумал определённую структуру данных что бы было удобно вытягивать с файла после десериализации.

```
[Serializable]
public class SimpleStoryData
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct StoryLevel
    {
        private byte _lvlMap;
        private bool _isView;
        private List<string> _piecesOfStory;

        public byte LvlMap => _lvlMap;
        public bool IsView => _isView;
        public List<string> PiecesOfStory => _piecesOfStory;

        public StoryLevel(byte levelMap, bool isView, List<string> piecesOfStory)
        {
            _lvlMap = levelMap;
            _isView = isView;
            _piecesOfStory = piecesOfStory;
        }

        public void SetIsView(bool value)
        {
            _isView = value;
        }
    }

    private List<StoryLevel> _storyLevels;
    public List<StoryLevel> StoryLevels => _storyLevels;

    public SimpleStoryData()
    {
        _storyLevels = new List<StoryLevel>();
    }

    public void AddStories(byte levelMap, bool isView, List<string> piecesOfStory)
    {
        _storyLevels.Add(new StoryLevel(levelMap, isView, piecesOfStory));
    }
}
```

> Этот класс предоставляет такую структуру.

И данные сериализуються и десериализуються так как мне нужно.

```
public class SimpleStoryLoader
{
    private string path;
    private SimpleStoryData data;

    public bool IsExists => File.Exists(path);

    public SimpleStoryLoader()
    {
        path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/simpleStory.story";
        data = new SimpleStoryData();
    }

    public bool TryInitiateData(List<GamePlotData> storyData, byte countLevels)
    {
        if (IsExists)
            return false;

        List<string> piecesStory = new List<string>();
        for (byte i = 1; i <= countLevels; i++)
        {
            var tmpData = storyData.Where(s => s.LevelMap == i).OrderBy(s => s.IdStep);

            foreach (var s in tmpData)
            {
                piecesStory.Add(s.Text);
            }

            data.AddStories(i, false, piecesStory);
        }
        Debug.Log("Create data");
        return true;
    }

    public List<string> LoadStories(byte levelMap)
    {
        if (data.StoryLevels.Exists(s => s.LvlMap == levelMap && !s.IsView))
            return data.StoryLevels.Find(s => s.LvlMap == levelMap).PiecesOfStory;
        return new List<string>();
    }

    public void LookedStories(byte levelMap)
    {
        if (data.StoryLevels.Exists(s => s.LvlMap == levelMap))
        {
            data.StoryLevels.Find(s => s.LvlMap == levelMap).SetIsView(true);
            SaveChangesToFile();
        }
    }

    public void LoadDataFromFile()
    {
        if (!IsExists)
            return;

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            data = (SimpleStoryData)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        }

        Debug.Log("Load");
    }

    public void SaveChangesToFile()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            bf.Serialize(fs, data);
        }

        Debug.Log("Save");
    }

    public void DeleteFile()
    {
        if (IsExists)
            File.Delete(path);
    }
}
```

> Класс отвечающий за сохранение и загрузку данных

```
public class storiesHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<GamePlotData> gamePlotData;
    [SerializeField] private byte countLevels;

    private SimpleStoryLoader simpleStoryLoader;

    private void Start()
    {
        simpleStoryLoader = new SimpleStoryLoader();
        if (!simpleStoryLoader.IsExists)
            if (simpleStoryLoader.TryInitiateData(gamePlotData, countLevels))
                simpleStoryLoader.SaveChangesToFile();
    }
}
```

> Класс MonoBehaviour.
> При запуске которого, проверяется есть ли файл. Если нету то идёт вызов TryInitiateData.
> Этот метод в свою очередь получает список ScriptableObject и уровень карты. Сортирует список и создаёт эту самую структуру данных. Он выполняет свою роботу.

При заходе на карту идёт загрузка данных с файла и вытягиваются данные которые нужны для этой текущего уровня карты. Дело в том что при просмотре данных, значение **_isView** должно поменяться на **true**. За это должен отвечать метод **LookedStories**. Дело в том что он не меняет значение.
Я поставил метку и подключился к Unity в режиме отладки и когда я опустился до метода **SetIsView** с struct StoryLevel, то там значение поменялось. Но когда я сделал шаг и указатель перешел на **SaveChangesToFile();** в методе **LookedStories()** то объект data также имел значение **false**. То есть в итоге изменений никаких не произошло. Я не могу понять в чем проблема. Помогите советом кто хоть немного понял мои мысли)

Comment: Блин, вообще бред какой-то! Ну как так? Значение должно меняться.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void LookedStories(byte levelMap)
    {
        SimpleStoryData tmp = new SimpleStoryData();
        data.StoryLevels.ForEach(s => {
            if (s.LvlMap == levelMap)
                tmp.AddStories(s.LvlMap, true, s.PiecesOfStory);
            else
                tmp.AddStories(s.LvlMap, s.IsView, s.PiecesOfStory);
        });

        SaveChangesToFile(tmp);

        /*if (data.StoryLevels.Exists(s => s.LvlMap == levelMap))
        {
            data.StoryLevels.Find(s => s.LvlMap == levelMap).SetIsView(true);
            //SaveChangesToFile();
        }*/
    }
```

Вообщем и целом я создаю новую дату и переписываю все данные со старой при этом меняю значение которое мне надо. И это работает. Вопрос остаётся - почему не меняется значение при старом коде. И переписывать все данные из-за одного значения как по мне зашквар. Поделитесь своим мнением по этому поводу, что бы я понимал в каком направлении двигаться.